# Easy way to prepare the environment for ES6 "import x" instead of "require(x)" in the express

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, import, require

I need a easy way for preparing the environment for **import x** instead of **require(x)** in the express project.

I found only methods where I can do it manually, but I think this is not the best way that can be.

Is there any npm package or GitHub template that prepares the environment for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .mjs file instead of .js file.
Documentation can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).

Or specify that you want to  use module as the [documentation shows](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#enabling)

But for scallable application, you should use well structured code.
For example using, [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) which is built with express out of the box. (It requires a minimal Typescript understand)